# Given $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow x_0} \frac{f(x)-a_0-a_1(x-x_0)-a_2(x-x_0)^2}{(x-x_0)^2} =0$ find a counterexample ....

Tags: real-analysis

> Give a counterexample of the following statement: if $f$ and $f'$ are continuous at $x_0$ and there are constant $a_0$, $a_1$, $a_2$ such that 
>   $$
> \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow x_0} \frac{f(x)-a_0-a_1(x-x_0)-a_2(x-x_0)^2}{(x-x_0)^2} =0
> $$
>   then $f''(x_0)$ exists.

RE-edit:

Given $f(x)=x^{4/3}$ and $f'(x)= \frac{4}{3} x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ both continuous $\forall x \in \mathbb R$

We have $f''(x)= \frac{4}{9} x^{-\frac{2}{3}}$ that is not continuous at $x_0=0$.

Is this correct? sufficient? Much appreciated

Comment: This is not what the question is asking. It is asking you to provide a specific $f$ and $x_0$ such that $f$ and $f'$ is continuous, the limit statement is true but $f''(x_0)$ does not exist.

Comment: @Jason I did a re-edit. thx for the input. Would it be correct? Otherwise, trying to have this clear: I understood that $a_2$ correspond to $f''(x_0)$; so  how can the limit statement be true if  f''(x_0) does not exist?

Comment: With your new example, what are the values of $a_0,a_1,a_2?$

Comment: It should also be said that showing $f''(x)$ is not continuous at $x_0$ does not prove $f''(x_0)$ fails to exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $f(x) = x^3\sin (1/x).\,\,\,$

Comment: that's an answer, not a hint

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Well, there's plenty left to do.

Comment: This is a hint, not an answer... All joke aside, I think the OP might be lost checking that $f''(0)$ does not exist hence recalling a definition here could prove useful.

Comment: @gegu "it follows that x does not exist at 0 " What does that mean? Apart from that, finding $f''(x)$ is not really the way to go here. Find $f'(x)$ and then show that $f''(0)$ fails to exist. Look at $(f'(x)-f'(0))/(x-0)$ as I think Did was suggesting.